# Keeping the same attribute in sync on two models in a Rails 2.x application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working in a large Rails 2.3 application and I have data on a model that would like to move to another model. I need to do this is phases as there are places in the Rails code base that are reading and writing this model data *and* outside applications reading the table data directly via SQL. I need to allow a period of time where the attribute is synchronized on both models and their associated tables before I drop one model and table altogether.

My models have a `has_one` and `belongs_to` relationship like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_email, :inverse_of => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_email
  validates_presence_of :email

  def email=( value )
    write_attribute(:email, value)
    user_email.write_attribute(:email, value)
  end
end

class UserEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :user_email
  validates_presence_of :email

  def email=( value )
    write_attribute(:email, value)
    user.write_attribute(:email, value)
  end
end
```

I'd like to do away with `UserEmail` and its associated table altogether, but for a time I need to keep `email` up-to-date on both models so if it's set on one model, it's changed on the other. Overriding `email=` on each model is straightforward, but coming up with a commit strategy is where I'm hitting a wall.

I have places in the code base that are doing things like:

```
user.user_email.save!
```

and I'm hoping to find a way to continue to allow this kind of code for the time being.

I can't figure out a way to ensure that saving an instance of `User` ensures the corresponding `UserEmail` data is committed  **and** saving an instance of `UserEmail` ensures the corresponding `User` instance data is also committed without creating an infinite save loop in the call backs.

This is the flow I would like to be able to support for the time being:

```
params = { user: { email: 'foo@bar.com', user_email: { email: 'foo@bar.com' } } }
user = User.create( params )
user.email = "moo@bar.com"
user.save
puts user.user_email # puts "moo@bar.com"
user.user_email.email = "foo@bar.com"
user.user_email.save
user.reload
puts user.email # puts "foo@bar.com"
```

**Is there a way to achieve this sort of synchronization between the `User` and `UserEmail` models so they are kept in sync?**

If it helps, I can probably do away with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_email` on `User`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume, for sanity's sake, that the models are "User" and "Cart", and the shared field is "email".  I would do this:

```
#in User
after_save :update_cart_email

def update_cart_email
  if self.changes["email"]
    cart = self.cart
    if cart.email != self.email
      cart.update_attributes(:email => self.email)
    end
  end
end

#in Cart
after_save :update_user_email

def update_user_email
  if self.changes["email"]
    user = self.user
    if user.email != self.email
      user.update_attributes(:email => user.email)
    end
  end
end
```

Because we check if the other model's email has already been set, it shouldn't get stuck in a loop.

This works if you drop `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_email` -- otherwise you'll get a save loop that never ends.

Comment: I've updated the question to use `User` and `UserEmail` as class names . Hopefully that's clearer. I also made it more explicit that I'd like the models to never drift so I'm overloading `email=` in both classes. In your code above, if I'm going to rely on `.changes["email"]` I'm pretty sure I'd have to accept that `email` would drift on models and not overload `email=` on them, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'drift'.

Comment: Their values wouldn't be the same until a save. Pre-save they could be different. I might be able to work around that though with similar logic and overriding the getter.

Comment: That would only be a problem though if you do actions in this order "change object A's email", "do something with object B", "save object A", which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

## Using [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveModel/Dirty)

In User model

```
after_save :sync_email, :if => :email_changed?
def sync_email
  user_email.update_column(:email, email) if user_email.email != email
end
```

In UserEmail model

```
after_save :sync_email, :if => :email_changed?
def sync_email
  user.update_column(:email, email) if user.email != email
end
```